# Is there a way to refresh extensions in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Hope I am asking this question in the right area, I am developing a couple of extensions for Inkscape and I was wondering if there is a way to refresh the extensions like GIMP has for script-fu? I have searched the web and documentation on Inkscape but couldn't find anything.

Thanks allot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, and found [this answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/248452):

> The INX files are only loaded at session start - for any updates or
>   newly installed extensions it is required to restart Inkscape.
>
> If only script files of already installed extensions have been
>   updated, there usually is no need to restart Inkscape - the content of
>   the script files is not cached (the script file is launched with the
>   external interpreter each time the extension is run).